# Pregunta sobre un div que se queda estático en una Landing Page

Tags: html5, css3

El problema es que a la hora de modificar el tamaño de la ventana del navegador, todos los elementos se adaptan de forma responsiva al cambio del browser. 
Menos el cuadro de texto que es un `<div></div>` con la clase descripcion la cual contiene únicamente texto dentro.

Mi código (también en [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Danielmagox/pen/POpvoG)):

```js
function validate(x){
emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

if (!emailRegex.test(x.value)) {
     x.style.color = "red";
    }else{
      x.style.color = "green";
    }
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";


::-webkit-input-placeholder { /*para el color del placeholder */
  color:white;
}

.cabecera{
  margin-top:-10px;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:#70708E;
  opacity:0.8;
}

.tcabecera{
  font-size:75px;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  color:#FCDDDD;
}

.descripcion{
  width:700px;
  height:200px;
  position:absolute;
  top:200px;
  left:100px;
  
}

.tdescripcion{
  font-size:25px;
  color:white;
  font-family:"Times New Roman";
  
}



body{
  background-image: url(https://cdn3.discotek.club/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/1468895860_maxresdefault.jpg);
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #464646;
}


#name, #mail{
  margin:5px;
  width:500px;
  background-color:#008CBA ; 
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#enviar{
  margin-top:10px;
  width:500px;
  background-color: #4CAF50; 
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#enviar:hover{
  background-color:rgb(35, 81, 35);
}

#enviar:active {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #666;
  transform: translateY(4px);
}

#campotexto{
  width:500px;
  height:200px;
  margin:5px 5px 5px 5px
  border-style: groove;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color:rgb(125, 170, 216);
}

.tb{
  color:white;
  font-size:20px;
}

.formu{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  margin-right:100px;
}

.relleno{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 
}

.botones{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>

<div class="cabecera">
   <text class="tcabecera"> Mar salada S.L </text>
       </div>

<div class="descripcion">
  <text class="tdescripcion">Bienvenido!, una vez atravesadas las puertas de este fantástico portal podrás disfrutar de nuestros maravillosos servicios , ofrecemos completa garantía tanto en la manuntención de Servidores para empresas medianas y pequeñas, La creación de Aplicaciones Web para las mismas empresas y además, por un pequeño plus, la contratación de un servicio de cyberseguridad. <br></br>                            
  Para cualquier duda/petición escriba algo en la caja.</text>
  </div>


<div class="formu">
<form action="pagina2.html" method="get" name="formulario">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="relleno" name="Nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
  <input type="email" id="mail" class="relleno" name="Email" placeholder="E-mail" onkeyup="validate(this)" required>
  <div class="botones">
  <input type="radio" id="boton1" class="opbutt" name="opciones" value="Servidores" checked>
     <label class="tb" for="boton1"> Servidores </label>
  <input type="radio" id="boton2" class="opbutt" name="opciones" value="Aplicaciones web">
    <label class="tb" for="boton2"> Aplicaciones web </label>
  <input type="radio" id="boton3" class="opbutt" name="opciones" value="Seguridad" >
    <label class="tb" for="boton3"> Seguridad </label>
    </div>
  
  <textarea name="comentario" class="relleno" id="campotexto" rows="50" cols="50"></textarea>
  
  <input type="submit" class="relleno" id="enviar" name="Enviar" value="Enviar" >
  
  </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: Dos comentarios sobre tu código: la etiqueta `<text>` no es de HTML sino de SVG, y para hacer un salto de línea no se hace `<br></br>`, `br`  es una etiqueta que no tiene cierre, as que basta con `<br>` o `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No ponga altura y anchura absoluta, ponle porcentaje.

```
.descripcion{

  width:700px; //<-- Pon un valor %

  height:200px; //<-- Pon un valor %

  position:absolute;

  top:200px;

  left:100px;
}
```